# Google Drive File Download

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to download file from google drive using the below mentioned code.
I have successfully tested other methods like insert file, delete file upload file, but when trying to download the file I get 401 authorization error at HttpResponse response = request.execute() in the below code.

```
private static synchronized InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) throws IOException 
    {
        //File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
        String fileURL = file.getDownloadUrl();
        GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl(fileURL);
        if (fileURL != null && fileURL.length() > 0) 
        {
            try {

                    HttpRequest request = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
                    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
                    InputStream inStream = response.getContent();

                    //HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url).execute();
                    System.out.println("content "+ inStream);
                    return inStream;
            } catch (IOException e) {

                // An error occurred.
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("downloadFile error :"+ e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        } else {
                    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                    return null;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried implementing using Async, still i get 401 error

```
08-30 19:31:13.917: W/System.err(1585): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
08-30 19:31:13.925: W/System.err(1585):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:978)
08-30 19:31:13.935: W/System.err(1585):     at com.rise.risedrive.RiseDriveActivity$DownloadFile.doInBackground(RiseDriveActivity.java:112)
08-30 19:31:13.945: W/System.err(1585):     at com.rise.risedrive.RiseDriveActivity$DownloadFile.doInBackground(RiseDriveActivity.java:1)
08-30 19:31:13.955: W/System.err(1585):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-30 19:31:13.955: W/System.err(1585):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-30 19:31:13.965: W/System.err(1585):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-30 19:31:13.965: W/System.err(1585):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-30 19:31:13.975: W/System.err(1585):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-30 19:31:13.975: W/System.err(1585):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-30 19:31:32.250: W/jdwp(1585): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
08-30 19:31:32.250: I/dalvikvm(1585): GC lifetime allocation: 2603 bytes
```

I have tried to debug it but couldn't
help me solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you print the error message? You can find out more about how to catch error from this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#catching_exceptions_with_client_libraries). The credentials might have expired or the user might have revoked access to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code are you setting the Authorization header.

You need something like

```
setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + "***ACCESS_TOKEN***");
```

For any 401/403 errors it's well worth getting your request working on the Oauth Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ so you have a datum on which to build your app.

Comment: `service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest()` should do that internally.